# Copy constructor for tree structure occasionally deletes leaves

Tags: java, tree, copy, copy-constructor

I have a tree-like structure and my copy constructor seems to be occasionally dropping some of my "leaves."

Basic structure:

```
public class Arrow {
   ArrayList<Arrow> subArrows;
   Interval start;
   Interval end;
}
```

Copy constructor:

```
public Arrow(Arrow other) {
    this.start = new Interval(other.start);
    this.end = new Interval(other.end);
    if (other.subArrows != null) {
        this.subArrows = new ArrayList<Arrow>();
        for (Arrow sub : other.subArrows) {
            this.subArrows.add(new Arrow(sub));
        }
    } else {
        this.subArrows = new ArrayList<Arrow>();
    }
}
```

I expected this to essentially do a deep-copy of my tree structure. Instead, I occasionally find that one of my `subArrows` arrays is empty. I haven't noticed a pattern other than that  they tend to be on the very lowest "level" of my tree.

Any ideas? I haven't used java in a while.

EDIT: A couple of people were asking for more code, so here are all the places that touch subArrows. This is from a pretty big algorithm/data structure so it would be unreasonable to post all of it.

Gets all of the subArrows recursively and returns a set of them.

```
Set<Arrow> allSubArrows(Arrow arrow) {
    Set<Arrow> arrowSet = new HashSet<Arrow>();
    if (arrow.subArrows != null && arrow.subArrows.size() > 0) {
        for (Arrow sub : arrow.subArrows) {
            arrowSet.addAll(allSubArrows(sub));
        }
        return arrowSet;
    } else {
        arrowSet.add(arrow);
        return arrowSet;
    }
}
```

Mathy reasons behind what this does, but subArrows modified at the bottom:

```
void enforceMonotonicity(Arrow arrow) {
    boolean changed = false;
    if (arrow.end != null && arrow.start != null) {
        if (arrow.start.isParallelTo(arrow.end)) {
            //either left to right or bottom to top
            if (arrow.start.isVertical()) {
                //left interval pointing to right interval
                if (arrow.start.startGraph.y > arrow.end.startGraph.y) {
                    arrow.end.startGraph.y = arrow.start.startGraph.y;
                    changed = true;
                }
                if (arrow.end.endGraph.y < arrow.start.endGraph.y) {
                    arrow.start.endGraph.y = arrow.end.endGraph.y;
                    changed = true;
                }
            } else {
                //bottom interval pointing to top interval
                if (arrow.start.startGraph.x > arrow.end.startGraph.x) {
                    arrow.end.startGraph.x = arrow.start.startGraph.x;
                    changed = true;
                }
                if (arrow.end.endGraph.x < arrow.start.endGraph.x) {
                    arrow.start.endGraph.x = arrow.end.endGraph.x;
                    changed = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (changed) {
        //check to make sure SOMETHING is still reachable, if not arrow = null
        if (arrow.start.isVertical()) {
            if (arrow.start.startGraph.y >= arrow.start.endGraph.y ||
                    arrow.end.startGraph.y >= arrow.end.endGraph.y) {
                arrow = null;
            }
        } else {
            if (arrow.start.startGraph.x >= arrow.start.endGraph.x ||
                    arrow.end.startGraph.x >= arrow.end.endGraph.x) {
                arrow = null;
            }
        }
        //if we changed the outer arrows, we need to recursively change the subarrows
        if (arrow != null && arrow.subArrows != null && arrow.subArrows.size() > 0) {
            for (Arrow sub : arrow.subArrows) {
                enforceMonotonicity(sub);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Part of a merging algorithm:

```
HashSet<Arrow> mergeCells(Set<Arrow> first, Set<Arrow> second) {
    HashSet<Arrow> mergedCell = new HashSet<Arrow>();
    //loop through arrows in adjacent cells and find the ones that connect
    for (Arrow topArrow : first) {
        for (Arrow bottomArrow : second) {
            if(topArrow.start.intersects(bottomArrow.end)) {
                //merge arrows
                Interval middle = topArrow.start.intersection(bottomArrow.end);
                Arrow newArrow = new Arrow();
                if (middle != null) {
                    //if they connect, we copy the two arrows, modify their connection,
                    //create a new arrow with the constituents as subarrows, and add that to the mergedcell
                    //after the mergedcell is created, we can delete the base arrows
                    Arrow topCopy = new Arrow(topArrow);
                    topCopy.start = middle;
                    Arrow bottomCopy = new Arrow(bottomArrow);
                    bottomCopy.end = middle;

                    newArrow.subArrows.add(topCopy);
                    newArrow.subArrows.add(bottomCopy);
                    newArrow.start = bottomCopy.start;
                    newArrow.end = topCopy.end;

                    //if end and middle are parallel, we need to project monotonicity
                    //monotonicity is already enforced within a single cell
                    //and enforcemonotonicity knows whether or not start and end are parallel
                    enforceMonotonicity(newArrow);
                }
                //enforceMonotonicity could null out the new arrow
                if (newArrow != null && !newArrow.isNull()) {
                    mergedCell.add(newArrow);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //keep the originals in case they can connect later on
    //(hashset doesn't allow duplicates, so no need to worry here)
    mergedCell.addAll(first);
    mergedCell.addAll(second);

    return mergedCell;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like some debugging is required ;)

Comment: This should be fine unless you are experiencing threading issues. BTW - `this.subArrows = new ArrayList<Arrow>();` happens in both cases - it can appear outside the `if`.

Comment: Why don't you instantiate `subArrows` just once, before the `if`?

Comment: Just missed that, thanks. But it doesn't really change anything (compiler probably takes care of it?)

Comment: Could `new Arrow(sub)` be failing quietly? I.e. perhaps it throws an exception which is caught and discarded elsewhere. For that matter - `new Interval` may also have this issue (which would explain why the array is empty).

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon That's a good idea, but honestly I'm not catching exceptions anywhere. (This is something of a "rough draft"). I checked  my Interval copy constructor and indeed, it was a shallow copy. But I still have this leaf dropping issue even having fixed that. Will edit with more code.

Comment: Are you sure you are really dropping entries? Could it be your toString method failing? How are you detecting the loss?

Comment: I'm checking the structure in a debugger and it's definitely dropping entries. Basically I create every possible leaf to every possible valid tree, then I "build up" the tree from those leaves. There can't exist a parent without "base" children, and the children are easy to identify (the intervals don't span > 1 on either the x or y axis, but I realize that's very specific to what this algorithm actually does). EDIT: I realize that may sound inefficient but it's essentially memoization, there are several different trees that can be built from the same base leaves.

Answer (score 0):

When `(other.subArrows == null)`, your code still creates `this.subArrows` by `new ArrayList<Arrow>()`. That's not a real clone(one is `null`, the other is NOT). If you want to make sure that subArrow is always non-null(which facilitate to add subArrow without checking `null`), you could instantiate it in the field definition.

If that still doesn't work, you may have to show more code since we don't know how you add subArrows in an Arrow. Besides, if your code is under multi-threaded environment, and the bug is hard to reproduce, it might be synchronization problem. Note that `ArrayList` is not thread-safe. Try `Vector` or `Collections.synchronizedList` instead, or properly synchronize critical block. Again, we don't have your related code.

BTW, declaring `List<Arrow> subArrows` is better than `ArrayList<Arrow> subArrows`.

Comment: That issue - although valid - cannot possibly drop "leaves" as the OP is complaining of.

Comment: I'm not sure. It may depend on how he adds `subArrows`. That's why I recommend he show more code.

Comment: Changing null subArrows to an empty list is actually what I want (I realize it's not an exact copy). And I'm not threading at all. Does java decide to thread things without me explicitly telling it to? (again, it's been a while)